# Workaround for third party cookie from server side

Tags: safari, cross-domain, setcookie, third-party-cookies

We have a customer having their own client UI application ([www.myclient.com](http://www.myclient.com)). When they make an API call to our server ([www.iamserver.com](http://www.iamserver.com)), we set cookies (Set-Cookie header) and send back in the response. We expect these cookies to be sent in the subsequent requests from the client. *[Third-Party-Cookies scenario]*
Problem: Recently, due to some org policy, our client browsers have been blocked from using third party cookie. Obviously, calls to our server are not going through since the cookies are not set.
Is there any workaround from server side that we can do without doing any change in the client application? Looking for answers only from the server side.

I tried changing the domain of the cookie we set to that of the client domain. It still won't work because the browser blocks the cookie saying "domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url".
Browser: chrome

Any references/pointers are deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance.